# Why \n is't working from database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I fill the **ListView** from **Database**. One of the fields in DB contains **text** with **\n**. But when I put this text into the item, then I don't get **Newline** instead of **\n**. How does I must  correctly take this text from DB and put it into the item?

My code:

```
txtComment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_comment);
this.cur.moveToPosition(position);
txtComment.setText(this.cur.getString(this.cur.getColumnIndex("comment")));
```

**In DB item:**

> The probe was built to land on the larger ... rock to bring back to Earth.\nSuch a venture should ...

**result in android:**

> The probe was built to land on the larger ... rock to bring back to Earth.\nSuch a venture should ...

**I expected:**

> The probe was built to land on the larger ... rock to bring back to Earth.
>
> Such a venture should ...

**TextView** from **item.xml**:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Content for **DB** I am taking by parsing JSON. I can ask developer to insert smth else instead of **\n**. But what?

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: I don't think this is related to DB. The DB just stores what it is given with. So there could be 2 issues: (1) you don't pass newlines to DB when you insert/update data or (2) your `TextView` is instructed (probably implicitly) to show the only line of text. Probably post your layout xml for list item.

Comment: @kabuko I've added what I've getting instead.

Comment: @Arhimed I've added TextView element from layout xml for list item.

Comment: @Svyatoslav: the TextView looks pretty ok - it should show several lines of text if they are present. The fact you see the only line may also be caused by list item layout. Usually the layout is instructed to have some predefined height and no more. So even if the text is multilined the text view will not expand its height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string containing a backslash followed by an n is very different to a string containing a newline. It's only when a string is parsed as a *string literal* that Java treats them differently. If you want to store a newline in a database, you should just store it in the value to start with. If you want to apply Java string literal escaping, you'll need to find some appropriate code to do so - which *isn't* just as simple as `text.replace("\\n", "\n")` for example, as you *also* need to take account of situations like `"escaped\\n"`.

I suspect there'll be some string utility libraries somewhere which can do this - the [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) class from Apache Commons 3.1 looks like a good starting point, if it works in Android, for example.